# Proguard java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation

I'm trying to obfuscate an android project with proguard and it fails with the error below:

```
 Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.obfuscate.ClassObfuscator.visitAnyAttribute(ClassObfuscator.java:169)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitSourceFileAttribute(SimplifiedVisitor.java:251)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.attribute.SourceFileAttribute.accept(SourceFileAttribute.java:60)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.attributesAccept(ProgramClass.java:535)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.obfuscate.ClassObfuscator.visitProgramClass(ClassObfuscator.java:148)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.attribute.EnclosingMethodAttribute.referencedClassAccept(EnclosingMethodAttribute.java:108)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.obfuscate.ClassObfuscator.visitEnclosingMethodAttribute(ClassObfuscator.java:182)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.attribute.EnclosingMethodAttribute.accept(EnclosingMethodAttribute.java:130)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.attributesAccept(ProgramClass.java:535)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.obfuscate.ClassObfuscator.visitProgramClass(ClassObfuscator.java:148)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.attribute.EnclosingMethodAttribute.referencedClassAccept(EnclosingMethodAttribute.java:108)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.obfuscate.ClassObfuscator.visitEnclosingMethodAttribute(ClassObfuscator.java:182)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.attribute.EnclosingMethodAttribute.accept(EnclosingMethodAttribute.java:130)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.attributesAccept(ProgramClass.java:535)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.obfuscate.ClassObfuscator.visitProgramClass(ClassObfuscator.java:148)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.attribute.EnclosingMethodAttribute.referencedClassAccept(EnclosingMethodAttribute.java:108)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.obfuscate.ClassObfuscator.visitEnclosingMethodAttribute(ClassObfuscator.java:182)
[2015-05-19 18:24:31 - Volume]  at proguard.classfile.attribute.EnclosingMethodAttribute.accept(EnclosingMethodAttribute.java:130)
```

and it goes on like this for 1000 lines with the same error

[*Update* ] **Proguard.cfg**

```
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.inject.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

-keepattributes *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod, Signature, InnerClasses

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class org.acra.ACRA {
    *;
}
-keep class org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode {
    *;
}
-keepnames class org.acra.sender.HttpSender$** {
    *;
}
-keepnames class org.acra.ReportField {
    *;
}
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void addCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void putCustomData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public void removeCustomData(java.lang.String);
}
-keep public class org.acra.ErrorReporter
{
    public void handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable);
}
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void onEvent*(**);
}
-keep class com.android.internal.telephony.* {
  *;
}
-keep class com.example.com.IncomingCallReceiver {
  *;
}

-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
-keep class com.daimajia.easing.** { *; }
-keep interface com.daimajia.easing.** { *; }

-keepnames class de.devland.** { *; }
-keep class **$$Impl { public *;}
-keep class preferences.**Prefs { public *;}
  # Dagger
    -dontwarn dagger.internal.codegen.**
    -keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
        @javax.inject.* *;
        @dagger.* *;
        <init>();
    }
    -keep class dagger.* { *; }
    -keep class javax.inject.* { *; }
    -keep class * extends dagger.internal.Binding
    -keep class * extends dagger.internal.ModuleAdapter
    -keep class * extends dagger.internal.StaticInjection
```

**What i've tried:**

1. Made sure I have all the libraries referenced
2. Ensured all neccessary  rules in proguard.cfg
3. I've added all the libraries and same
       configuration to a new project in order to try and replicate the
       problem and couldn't. Only when I copied the source code did the
       problem appear, which leads me to think that the error in in the
       source code. But since the error message is too ambiguous, I don't
       know where to start.

**Can anybody tell me any ideas for a next step or how I can debug proguard?

Thank you!**

Comment: also post your proguard rules

Comment: @goonerDroid updated with the proguard.cfg. Any ideas?

Comment: there is something wrong with code in ' main'.I can't find anything wrong in your proguard rules

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @f470071 No! Migrated to Android Studio, rebuild with all the libraries and it disappeared. I guess we'll never know...

Comment: in my case it was proguard. I downloaded the newest version from proguard site.